# drawing multiple circles in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I have a code that draws a circle in this way:

```
QList< QPair<double, double> > vertices;
//constructor
vertices.clear();
calculateWhiteVetices();

//drawing methods
void MyGLWidget::drawWhiteCircle() {
    int n = vertices.count();
    qglColor(Qt::white);
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        glVertex2f(vertices[i].first, vertices[i].second);
    }
    glEnd();
}


void MyGLWidget::calculateWhiteVetices()
{
    double a = 3.14 / 90;
    vertices.append(QPair<double, double> (0,0));
    for(int i = 0; i <= 360; i++) {
        vertices.append(QPair<double, double> (cos(i * a) * radius, sin(i * a) * radius));
    }
}

//paintGL method
glPushMatrix();
glTranslatef(randx , randy , 0);
drawWhiteCircle();
glPopMatrix();
```

now I want to add another circle here, but there's a problem;
The colors are mixed together and the shape is ruined. This is the code:

```
QList< QPair<double, double> > blueVertices;
//constructor
blueVertices.clear();
calculateBlueVetices();
```

replacing each `vertices` with `blueVertices` in new methods and put the methods exactly next to white circle's methods.
and put this part of code right after the `glPopMatrix();` in the `paintGL` method.

```
//paintGL method
glPushMatrix();
glTranslatef(randx-0.2f , randy-0.2f , 0);
drawBlueCircle();
glPopMatrix();
```

I know the vertices are mixing somewhere because of my bad definition but I don't know where... . What is my fault here? 
This is my output:

Answer (score 0):

You can draw both circles side-by-side with some distance just to verify you are generating correct vertices. Just to start with you can try White circle with **`glTranslatef(radius , 0 , 0);`** and Blue with **`glTranslatef( -radius , 0 , 0);`** to check if both have required vertices

Comment: This is what I see in the output:
http://cdn.persiangig.com/preview/cB0T17KyYd/Capturea.png

Comment: looks like point(0,0) is having different colour values while draw call. Can you try replacing  qglColor() with glColor3f(1,1,1);